# How to give confirmation box before deleting multiple rows in php

Tags: php

I want to give confirmation message before deleting multiple rows. Below is code. Please suggest me how to give confirmation message before deleting the records.

```
    $sql="SELECT * FROM employee";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
    ?>

    <?php
    while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    ?>

    <tr>
    <td><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="<? echo     $rows['id']; ?>"></td>
    <td><? echo $rows['id']; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $rows['name']; ?></td>
    </tr>

    <?php
    }
    ?>

    <tr>
    <td><input name="delete" type="submit" id="delete" value="Delete"></td>
    </tr>

    <?php


    if($delete){
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
    $del_id = $checkbox[$i];
    $sql = "DELETE FROM employee WHERE id='$del_id'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    }

    if($result){
    echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=delete_multiple.php\">";
    }
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: have you tried an on click listener to show "var yn= confirm('Are You sure?');" then have an if(yn==true) //Delete if(yn==false) //do not delete ?

Comment: ya i did that, but the problem is if i will select 3 checkboxes to delete, then this confirmation box will appear 3 times because it is in a loop.

Comment: hmmm ok I'll have another think!

Answer (score 0):

Create a form with a check if that form is submitted, when the user submits that form you can send a request to delete. If not the code will not run the delete request?

Comment: Above code is what you are telling. I have just posted the code snippet here.